# Why can't I do tupleVar.get(3) or .get<3>()?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I was going over C++0x. As i looked at [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Tuple_types) I saw this example. Why do I need to do `get<3>(var)`? Why can't I do `var.get(index)` or `var.get<index>()`? I prefer these to make code look and feel consistant.

```
typedef tuple< int, double, long &, const char * > test_tuple ;
long lengthy = 12 ;
test_tuple proof( 18, 6.5, lengthy, "Ciao!" ) ;
lengthy = get<0>(proof) ;  // Assign to 'lengthy' the value 18.
get<3>(proof) = " Beautiful!" ;  // Modify the tuple’s fourth element.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `get<0>` because the tuple has a different type for each of its members. Therefore result type of `get<0>` is `int`, `get<1>` is `double`, `get<2>` is `long&` etc. You cannot achieve this when calling `get(0)` as it has to have a fixed return type.

You might also want to have a look at template metaprogramming because this pattern is one of the basic ones in this whole part of programming.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html

Comment: oh yeah... I completely forgot. I knew my C++ was rusty. Thanks for the major reminder.

Comment: And of course, the reason you *can* write `var[3]` in Python is that it's a dynamically-typed language.